# How to trigger a google cloud function with inputs

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

In the script below, I have manually assigned string values to the 4 variables (college, department, course, section).

```
import pandas as pd

def open_seats(request):
  college = "ENG"
  department = "EC"
  course = "414"
  section = "A1"

  url = 'https://www.bu.edu/link/bin/uiscgi_studentlink.pl/1630695081?ModuleName=univschr.pl&SearchOptionDesc=Class+Number&SearchOptionCd=S&KeySem=20223&ViewSem=Fall+2021&College=' \
        + college + '&Dept=' + department + '&Course=' + course + '&Section=' + section


  table = pd.read_html(url)[4]
  class_table = table['Class']
  open_seats_table = table['OpenSeats']

  new_table = pd.concat([class_table, open_seats_table], axis=1)


  full_section_string = college + '\u00A0' + department + course + '\u00A0' + section

  for i in range(len(new_table)):
    if new_table['Class'][i] == full_section_string:
      val = new_table['OpenSeats'][i]
      break

  return val
```

I would like to connect this script to a mobile app where the user is asked to input the data for these 4 variables. So instead of having them manually labeled, how can I assign the variables the data that comes from the trigger?

At first, I thought that the data would be sent as a JSON in the form:

```
{
"college":"ENG",
"department":"EC"
"course":"414",
"section":"A1"
}
```

So I updated the code to look like this:

```
def open_seats(request):
  college = request["college"]
  department = request["department"]
  course = request["course"]
  section = request["section"]
```

I am lacking some fundamental knowledge about the way the http trigger functions, and how I can pass inputs to the cloud functions through the http trigger.

Comment: It turns out I was not knowledgeable about URL parameters and how to query variables in a URL. This link helped me with my issue: https://us-east4-persuasive-yeti-325421.cloudfunctions.net/open_seats.

Answer (score 0):

using the below code I got a response of 12

```
import pandas as pd
college = "ENG"
department = "EC"
course = "414"
section = "A1"

def open_seats(a,b,c,d):

    url_base = 'https://www.bu.edu/link/bin/uiscgi_studentlink.pl/1630695081?ModuleName=univschr.pl&SearchOptionDesc=Class+Number&SearchOptionCd=S&KeySem=20223&ViewSem=Fall+2021&College='

    url = url_base + a + "&Dept=" + b + "&Course=" + c + "&Section=" + d
    table = pd.read_html(url)[4]
    class_table = table['Class']
    open_seats_table = table['OpenSeats']
    new_table = pd.concat([class_table, open_seats_table], axis=1)


    full_section_string = a + '\u00A0' + b + c + '\u00A0' + d

    for i in range(len(new_table)):
        if new_table['Class'][i] == full_section_string:
            val = new_table['OpenSeats'][i]
            return print(f'{val}')
# I call the function with the predefined variables being passed
open_seats(college,department,course,section)
```

what data are you trying to pass to `open_seats(request)` ?

```
def open_seats(request):
  college = request["college"]
  department = request["department"]
  course = request["course"]
  section = request["section"]
```

You didn't post the raw data coming from the app to the script. if you could post it, I would be able to give a full answer.

also the code you are using to take user input?